# Masculin ou féminin: « Pour le [...] qu'a [...] »

Tags: grammaire, accord, conjugaison, participe-passé

Est-ce qu'on dit :

« Pour la fête qu'a organisée Pierre » ou « Pour la fête qu'a organisé Pierre » ?

De plus, si on parle d'une femme, est-ce qu'on dit :

« Pour la fête qu'a organisée Chantal » ou « Pour la fête qu'a organisé Chantal » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le COD de la subordonnée est « la fête », repris par « que », qui est féminin et est placé avant le verbe. On écrit donc:

> Pour la fête qu'a organisée Pierre.

S'il s'agissait d'un concours on écrirait :

> Pour le concours qu'a organisé Pierre.

Cela ne dépend pas du sujet de la subordonnée (ici, la personne qui a organisé l'évènement).